# How to integrate Amazon lex with MS Bot framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, amazon-lex, bot-framework-composer

I would like to integrate Amazon Lex with the Microsoft Bot Framework.

There is a default integration between Microsoft LUIS NLP and the Microsoft Bot Framework but we want to integrate with Amazon Lex instead. Is there a way that such an integration can be achieved and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the exact same thing, and am having a lot of difficulty! At the moment I have found you can connect MS Bot Composer with Alexa using a built in configuration in Composer, I thought that might be a compromise, but there are problems connecting Alexa to an AWS account. I am currently investigating putting Twilio in between Lex and MS Bot as another possible solution.